# C# File Modify Access Denied Even When Admin On Owned Environment

Tags: c#, file, exception, permission-denied, access-denied

I have a weird issue with my computer.

I cannot use my C# apps to rename or delete files on my desktop and in other specific directories on my computer.
There's no real pattern and the information is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace justATest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            string path = @"C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\";
            string nameBefore = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");
            string nameAfter = Path.Combine(path, "something.txt");

            File.Move(nameBefore, nameAfter); // Fails
        }
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path is denied.
  Source=System.IO.FileSystem
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.FileSystem.MoveFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at justATest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\justATest\justATest\Program.cs:line 16
```

What I tried:

1. I updated Windows to the latest version
2. I checked the file's owner
3. I checked the file's permissions
4. I ran my app as an administrator
5. I ran Visual Studio as an administrator
6. I ran SFC /ScanNow
7. I did some kind of a repair to my Windows installation (through Microsoft Support)
8. I created multiple files and tried it on old and new files
9. I created nested folders and tried to rename files within said folders
10. I tried renaming files in other directories (that works)
11. I tried the method of copying the file into a new file (with the new name) and then deleting the old file. This works until I try to delete the old file, which fails
12. I tried doing the same tasks manually and it works just fine
13. I tried turning off my anti virus
14. I tried to repair Visual Studio

I mainly want to rename files, but the same goes for deleting files and the like.

OS: Windows 10 Pro 21H2
IDE: Visual Studio 2019 16.11.15
Number of users on machine: 1 (just me)

If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: I would suggest the [sysinternals Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) (List Open Handles) tool, you can get "access denied" if another program has the file open (often but not limited to antivirus, folder sync programs like Dropbox or Google Drive Desktop can also be involved).  If the culprit is a Windows Explorer plugin, it might not stop explorer from doing the action, but stops your program.

Comment: Have you tried performing other types of file operations using C# on your computer? Try creating a directory. See if it works

Comment: I tried using the handle tool, it shows the file as unused.
"No matching handles found."
-
Also I can copy and paste a file in C# but not delete or rename a file.
Creating directories works too. But I can't create files.

Comment: Does the current user have full control on the folder you are trying to make those changes ?

Comment: As I stated in the original post, I'm the only user on the machine (which also means that I'm the administrator) and the file is literally on my desktop or within nested folders on my desktop. I even tried creating files with C#, but I literally can't create files on my desktop, only directories. This works fine NEARLY anywhere else (some folders for some reason don't want to allow these actions like my desktop, and some do).

Comment: The fact you are administrator doesn't mean as much as you think. An adminstrator can still be denied access to files, and may need to take ownership (which they have the right to) and then change security ACLs in order to access/modify files. Admittedly it would be weird to have that problem on your own desktop, but it's possible. Please show the result of the Powershell command `Get-Acl -Path yourfilehere  | Format-Table -Wrap`

Comment: Path        Owner                 Access
----        -----                 ------
example.txt MY-MACHINE\USERN BUILTIN\Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                                  BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                                  MY-MACHINE\USERN Allow  FullControl
I replaced my username with USERN and my machine ID with MY-MACHINE.
Also, as I stated above, I tried taking ownership of both the desktop and the file.

Comment: @Charlieface, the powershell command idea IS BRILLIANT!